# Python regex returns incorrect group

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have the following problem in python:

```
searchstring = "([A-Z0-9]*)_"
basename = "AK4RAE00005_ALL_MEASUREMENT.a2l"
m = re.search(searchstring, basename)
if m and m.group(0):
  print m.group(0)
```

I expected the result to be: `AK4RAE00005` but instead it is `AK4RAE00005_` 
I checked my RegEx on https://regexr.com/ and it finds the correct group without the underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try m.group(1)

m.group(0) matches the entire string.

```
searchstring = "([A-Z0-9]*)_"
basename = "AK4RAE00005_ALL_MEASUREMENT.a2l"
m = re.search(searchstring, basename)
if m:
    print m.group(1)
```

Comment: Simple as that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The result shown is correct, but the confusion is understandable. Actual group contents are indexed starting at 1. `m.group(1) == 'AK4RAE00005'`, as expected. Group zero is the entire match, capture groups and all, which is `'AK4RAE00005_'` because your pattern includes an underscore.